# Leaflet map modify tilt angle

Tags: dictionary, leaflet

Good day, I would to be able to modify the tilting angle ofthe leaflet map as we can this in this link : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/webgl/tilt-rotation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leaflet has no builtin functionality for rotation or tilt.

You can definitely implement rotation, look at this library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/leaflet-rotate

Unfortunately there is no library that I'm aware of that implements tilt control in leaflet.
You should have a look at other map libraries, especially at **mapbox**.
Mapbox have built in control for pitch and bearing: https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/set-perspective/

Comment: can we implement the cluster group functionality of leaflet in mapbox library?

Comment: yes, https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/cluster/